# Raw data is I(1) yet is I(0) in logs. Why?

Tags: data-transformation, stationarity, logarithm, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I'm curious how this is possible. The data in question, based on the ADF, we strongly fail to reject the null of a unit root. Yet in natural logs, the series is stationary apparently (ie, reject the null as p-value is 0.00).

But even in natural logs, the ACF shows high persistence, and it may as well be an MA(inf) based on the ACF. Also the PACF has a spike at lag=1, but nothing else anywhere. Hence the ACF/PACF seem to indicate a unit root even in natural logs, but the ADF doesn't.

How come?

Comment: Could you include graphs of the logged series and its ACF/PACF?

Comment: @RichardHardy, sure... Sorry but how do I include graphs, etc.?

Comment: There is a picture symbol in the top bar when writing/editing an answer/question.